# When I use bootstrapping to calculate confidence intervals for accuracy, should I resample the entire dataset or just the test set?

Tags: statistics

In [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-machine-learning-results-python/) article, the author resamples the entire dataset and retrains the model each time. However, I don't see why you couldn't just resample the test set only, which is what I'm currently doing.

In my case, I'm doing text classification and have around 80,000 unlabeled tweets, and 2,000 labeled tweets. I split the 2000 into 1700/300, then trained and saved a model on the 1700. In order to find confidence intervals for accuracy, I resample the 300 test set with replacement 300 times and use the saved model to predict on that new set of 300, then repeat that a lot of times to get a distribution for accuracy. Finally, I use this saved model to predict labels for the 80,000 unlabeled tweets.

To me, this seems better than resampling the entire set and then retraining (what the article does) because

1) It's much faster

2) I want to know the saved model's accuracy confidence interval, because that's the model I'll be using to predict labels on the large set. I don't care how well it does if it was trained on a different set of tweets.

Why is this approach not the correct way?